# Zend Framework http requests prefixing parent domain instead of subdomain on shared host

Tags: zend-framework, subdomain, shared-hosting

I have added a standard zend project into a directory off the root on a shared host.
I created a subdomain sub1.

```
parent domain www.main.com
sub domain    sub1.main.com
```

The rewrite rules seem to be working.  When I enter sub1.main.com I get my main page to the project.
However, any anchor tag or request I create using the zend MVC relative path is prefixed with www.main.com instead of sub1.main.com and it give me a page not found error.

If I enter into the browsers url line as sub1.main.com/index/index or any other valid request it will pull in the correct view script and display just fine.

How do I get Zend to prefix to the subdomain and not the parent domain?  Is this done in index.php or will this be in the bootstrap or in .htaccess?

```
Ex. <a href="/app/index">App Controller</a>
```

The above request is looking like:
http://www.main.com/app/index 
it needs to be:
      http://sub1.main.com/app/index

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear on exactly what you have going on. If you echo this:

```
<a href="/app/index">App Controller</a>
```

...it is being rewritten to this:

```
<a href="http://www.main.com/app/index">App Controller</a>
```

?

What are you actually doing to create the HTML links?